# Two controllers different HTML pages using same factory in Angularjs, but array is not updating on one?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am stuck with Angular. I am trying to update an array on two different HTML pages, but this does not work. I tested this with giving the array an initial value and both pages display the values properly. Only when updating nothing happens on one page. I have tried these two things, but no luck and no errors in the console:

```
  .controller("ctrl1", function ($scope, Sender) {
        $scope.Sender = Sender;
        $scope.paired = Sender.paired;
        })

    .controller("ctrl2", function ($scope, Sender) {
        $scope.Sender = Sender;
        $scope.paired = Sender.paired;
        })

    .factory("Sender", function () {
        return {
            paired: [],
            fn: function (val) {
            this.paired.push(val);
              }
        }
    })
```

And this:

```
  .controller("ctrl1", function ($scope, Sender) {
        $scope.Sender = Sender;
        $scope.paired = Sender.paired;
        })

    .controller("ctrl2", function ($scope, Sender) {
        $scope.Sender = Sender;
        $scope.paired = Sender.paired;
        $scope.$watch('Sender.paired', function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        if(newVal) { 
        scope.paired = newVal;
    }
  });
        })

    .factory("Sender", function () {
        return {
            paired: [],
            fn: function (val) {
            this.paired.push(val);
              }
            }
        })
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: `Only when updating nothing happens on one page` where are you updating?

Comment: @PSL I did not include all that because it seemed irrelevant. I am updating in the factory itself.

Comment: What makes you think it is irrelevant if you overwrite the reference of array in the factory it wont work right

Comment: @PSL I am not sure what you mean but this is how I update the array + I output it immediately on both pages. One gets the values and the other not. Why should the reference be overwritten? Ow and the update happens with a simple ng-click.

Comment: `Why should the reference be overwritten?` --> i commented before you updated your question with factory implementation. Works fine for me. http://plnkr.co/edit/ORdXGa?p=preview

Comment: @PSL I tested this also and it works also for me, but when I move it to a different HTML page then it starts not updating anymore. On the same page it is fine. I see that you used `mainctrl` is that maybe why my code is not working?

Comment: Please show a demo. Ignore MainCtrl, that was part of default angular template from plnkr

Comment: But if I remove MainCtrl and concat ctrl1 to `app.` your code also stops working...

Comment: I just removed mainCtrl. works just fine.http://plnkr.co/edit/w2nJ5l?p=preview

Comment: Yep...I am 100% sure I need some rest now :) That was stupid. I didn't remove it from the HTML. I will take a fresh look at it another time.

Comment: Yeah long day perhaps!! :)

Comment: @PSL Definetly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok this is simply not working. I think each HTML page has his own local factory. I will go with Angularfire to achieve what I want. I think that is even a more elegant solution :)